# Jquery, getting style: background (not background-color), border, etc, can't figure out how to do this

Tags: jquery, css, element

It seems that firefox automatically combines things, such as it takes individual css values, such as for "border-color", "border-width" and dumps them all into "border".. this makes things a pain for jquery as the .css selector can only select the individual ones, like "border-color", not just "border" or "background".. I need to get the full value of "border" or "background" so that I can parse it to get the values I need.. I have read other posts and have tried the following but its not giving back the value:

```
test = $("#mydiv").attr("border");
```

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to do this instead:

```
test = $("#mydiv").css("border");
```

EDIT: ok you can use plain old javascript:

```
test = $("#mydiv")[0].style.border
```

Comment: @Rick just read your post better. I see what you are saying about css not pulling correctly. I have not noticed a problem with this but I will check it out real quick.

Comment: @smerriman here is the documentation from the css jquery docs. 

Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported.

Comment: It says in the .css documentation for jquery that it can't get the shorthand, it doesn't work for me in trying that.. I will try the regular javascript way